# Difference in time based on time records and subequent time records from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I placed a sample of some data on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f6beb/1) where I'm trying to figure out how to build a query from this data that will give:

1. The [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) of the `TimeStr` field of the `scl1_fill` table and the very next `sc1_weight` table `TimeStr` field

   - *example:* `SELECT TIMEDIFF('2017-11-14 07:21:29','2017-11-14 07:15:56')`
     [image]

I think I need to emulate [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) with MySQL and I always seem to have trouble with that for some reason using variables and sub queries to get the row numbers, etc.

I tried quite a few things and came up short every time so not even sure it's worth showing what I tried so I will provide what I have and the expected results for visualization/clarification.

---

Essentially when the `sc1_fill` gets a `1` value the device starts to fill and when the `sc1_weight` gets any value then that means it met the weight setpoint and gives back a value at that point.

Getting the time difference between the two will show the amount of time it took from the time the `sc1_fill` started until the very next record time wise the `sc1_weight` gets any value ran.

I figured I could throw this as a value on the `sc1_weight` records with the [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) and have a new column and have all other records show `NULL` and that'd work (see **Expected Results**).

---

### [Full Table Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f6beb/1)

*(Always and only get data from one specific date so e.g. `WHERE TimeStr LIKE '2017-11-14%'`)*

```
| test_tbl |               TimeStr |   Value |
----------------------------------------------
sc1_setpnt      2017-11-14 00:05:01     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 07:10:24     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 07:15:56     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 07:21:29     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 07:26:18     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 07:27:32     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 07:33:07     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 08:18:36     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 08:19:53     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 08:25:29     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 08:30:21     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 08:31:39     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 08:37:20     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 08:46:00     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 08:47:17     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 08:52:50     649
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 09:03:22     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 09:04:36     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 09:10:10     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 09:18:45     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 09:20:35     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 09:26:11     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 09:36:40     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 09:37:59     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 09:43:39     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 09:46:55     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 09:53:49     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 09:59:42     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 10:36:06     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 10:37:27     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 10:43:14     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 10:50:44     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 10:52:01     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 10:57:47     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 11:05:46     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:07:19     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 11:12:48     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 11:25:25     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:36:18     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:39:12     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:45:26     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 11:50:39     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 12:00:45     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 12:04:44     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 12:10:16     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 12:58:48     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 13:00:01     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 13:05:23     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 13:06:19     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 13:10:52     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 13:16:19     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 13:18:27     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 13:24:35     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 13:30:01     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 13:31:35     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 13:35:40     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 13:41:05     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 13:47:04     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 13:50:19     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 13:55:43     649
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 14:06:57     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 14:08:11     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 14:13:32     651
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 14:26:10     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 14:27:24     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 14:32:49     650
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 14:42:00     1
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 14:43:11     1
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 14:48:25     650
```

---

### Expected Results

```
| test_tbl |               TimeStr |   Value |     FillTime |
-------------------------------------------------------------
sc1_setpnt      2017-11-14 00:05:01     650              NULL   
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 07:10:24     1                NULL
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 07:15:56     1                NULL
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 07:21:29     651          00:05:33
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 07:26:18     1                NULL
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 07:27:32     1                NULL
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 07:33:07     650          00:05:35       
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 08:18:36     1                NULL
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 08:19:53     1                NULL
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 08:25:29     651          00:05:36
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 08:30:21     1                NULL
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 08:31:39     1                NULL
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 08:37:20     650         00:05:41
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 08:46:00     1                NULL
```

---

### Making Matters Worse

Okay to make matters worse, it seems at times there are multiple `sc1_fill` values of `1` before the subsequent `sc1_weight` value but I would only need to calculate the most recent or newest `TimeStr` of the set to get the fill time (e.g. `SELECT TIMEDIFF('2017-11-14 11:50:39','2017-11-14 11:45:26')`)

[image]

**Expected results where this is the case**

```
| test_tbl |               TimeStr |   Value |     FillTime |
-------------------------------------------------------------
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:36:18     1               NULL
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:39:12     1               NULL
sc1_fill        2017-11-14 11:45:26     1               NULL
sc1_weight      2017-11-14 11:50:39     651         00:05:13
sc1_disch       2017-11-14 12:00:45     1               NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you didn't request this summary output, I arrived at an approach that may be of use, a result looks like this

```
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
|    | filllno | weight |     start_fill      |      end_fill       | duration | num_of_fills |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 |       0 |    651 | 14.11.2017 07:15:56 | 14.11.2017 07:21:29 | 00:05:33 |            1 |
|  2 |       1 |    650 | 14.11.2017 07:27:32 | 14.11.2017 07:33:07 | 00:05:35 |            1 |
|  3 |       2 |    651 | 14.11.2017 08:19:53 | 14.11.2017 08:25:29 | 00:05:36 |            1 |
|  4 |       3 |    650 | 14.11.2017 08:31:39 | 14.11.2017 08:37:20 | 00:05:41 |            1 |
|  5 |       4 |    649 | 14.11.2017 08:47:17 | 14.11.2017 08:52:50 | 00:05:33 |            1 |
|  6 |       5 |    651 | 14.11.2017 09:04:36 | 14.11.2017 09:10:10 | 00:05:34 |            1 |
|  7 |       6 |    650 | 14.11.2017 09:20:35 | 14.11.2017 09:26:11 | 00:05:36 |            1 |
|  8 |       7 |    650 | 14.11.2017 09:37:59 | 14.11.2017 09:43:39 | 00:05:40 |            1 |
|  9 |       8 |    650 | 14.11.2017 09:53:49 | 14.11.2017 09:59:42 | 00:05:53 |            1 |
| 10 |       9 |    650 | 14.11.2017 10:37:27 | 14.11.2017 10:43:14 | 00:05:47 |            1 |
| 11 |      10 |    650 | 14.11.2017 10:52:01 | 14.11.2017 10:57:47 | 00:05:46 |            1 |
| 12 |      11 |    650 | 14.11.2017 11:07:19 | 14.11.2017 11:12:48 | 00:05:29 |            1 |
| 13 |      12 |    651 | 14.11.2017 11:45:26 | 14.11.2017 11:50:39 | 00:05:13 |            3 |
| 14 |      13 |    651 | 14.11.2017 12:04:44 | 14.11.2017 12:10:16 | 00:05:32 |            1 |
| 15 |      14 |    651 | 14.11.2017 13:00:01 | 14.11.2017 13:05:23 | 00:05:22 |            1 |
| 16 |      15 |    650 | 14.11.2017 13:10:52 | 14.11.2017 13:16:19 | 00:05:27 |            1 |
| 17 |      16 |    651 | 14.11.2017 13:24:35 | 14.11.2017 13:30:01 | 00:05:26 |            1 |
| 18 |      17 |    650 | 14.11.2017 13:35:40 | 14.11.2017 13:41:05 | 00:05:25 |            1 |
| 19 |      18 |    649 | 14.11.2017 13:50:19 | 14.11.2017 13:55:43 | 00:05:24 |            1 |
| 20 |      19 |    651 | 14.11.2017 14:08:11 | 14.11.2017 14:13:32 | 00:05:21 |            1 |
| 21 |      20 |    650 | 14.11.2017 14:27:24 | 14.11.2017 14:32:49 | 00:05:25 |            1 |
| 22 |      21 |    650 | 14.11.2017 14:43:11 | 14.11.2017 14:48:25 | 00:05:14 |            1 |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/TDAT97188)

```
select
      case when value = 1 then fillno else fillno-2 end filllno
    , max(value)                                        weight
    , max(case when value = 1 then TimeStr end)         start_fill
    , max(TimeStr)                                      end_fill
    , timediff(max(TimeStr),max(case when value = 1 then TimeStr end)) duration
    , count(*) - 1                                      num_of_fills
from (
      SELECT * 
      , IF(value <> 1, @prev := value, @prev) pweight
      , IF(value <> 1, @counter := @counter+1, @counter - 1) fillno
      FROM test_tbl
      cross join (select @counter :=0, @prev:=0) vars
      where tbl in ('sc1_fill','sc1_weight','sc1_setpnt')
      order by TimeStr ASC
    ) d
where tbl in ('sc1_fill','sc1_weight')
group by
    case when value = 1 then fillno else fillno-2 end
order by start_fill ASC
;
```

The inner subquery prepares the rows with information that will align the fills to weight (via "fillno") and hence permits the aggregated view you see above. Those rows look like this sample:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+
|    |    tbl     |       TimeStr       | Value | @counter :=0 | @prev:=0 | pweight | fillno |
+----+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+
|  1 | sc1_setpnt | 14.11.2017 00:05:01 |   650 |            0 |        0 |     650 |      1 |
|  2 | sc1_fill   | 14.11.2017 07:15:56 |     1 |            0 |        0 |     650 |      0 |
|  3 | sc1_weight | 14.11.2017 07:21:29 |   651 |            0 |        0 |     651 |      2 |
|  4 | sc1_fill   | 14.11.2017 07:27:32 |     1 |            0 |        0 |     651 |      1 |
|  5 | sc1_weight | 14.11.2017 07:33:07 |   650 |            0 |        0 |     650 |      3 |
|  6 | sc1_fill   | 14.11.2017 08:19:53 |     1 |            0 |        0 |     650 |      2 |
|  7 | sc1_weight | 14.11.2017 08:25:29 |   651 |            0 |        0 |     651 |      4 |
|  8 | sc1_fill   | 14.11.2017 08:31:39 |     1 |            0 |        0 |     651 |      3 |
|  9 | sc1_weight | 14.11.2017 08:37:20 |   650 |            0 |        0 |     650 |      5 |
| 10 | sc1_fill   | 14.11.2017 08:47:17 |     1 |            0 |        0 |     650 |      4 |
| 11 | sc1_weight | 14.11.2017 08:52:50 |   649 |            0 |        0 |     649 |      6 |
| 12 | sc1_fill   | 14.11.2017 09:04:36 |     1 |            0 |        0 |     649 |      5 |
+----+------------+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

The logic does account for 2 or more fill events as requested but also counts these so you can see any that have occurred.

Comment: I enjoyed the question, nicely prepared too (thanks!). I have one correction to the query, the order by should be based on `start_fill` I will edit the question too.

Comment: Afraid I don't have a place to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.TimeStr
        from Detail t2
        where t2.TimeStr < t.TimeStr and
              t2.tbl = 'sc1_fill' and t2.value = 1
        order by t2.TimeStr desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_timestamp
from Detail t
where t.tbl = 'sc1_weight';
```

You can then get the time difference from `timestamp` and `prev_timestamp`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8fc0f/8) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @Facebook . . . There was a misspelling (and then I also left out the `limit`).